# Gnome3/dock: instead of switching workspaces, open new window when icon clicked in dock

Tags: gnome, dock

I've been a Compiz/MATE/GNOME2 user for the past 16 years, and am finalllllly thinking about GNOME3.  I've got it set up, but I'm really annoyed that when I click an icon in the dock, it goes to the workspace with other already-opened programs (e.g., extant terminals).  I want the terminal to open in my current workspace; I know how to get to those other ones if I want them.  Any idea how to make that happen?

Answer (score 0):

By default, icons in Gnome Shell have a "Launch or Switch-to" behavior. When you click the icon, you are taken to a running instance of the application. If none is open, the application is started.

To override this behavior a single time, hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> while clicking the icon.

To change this behavior permanently, enable the Gnome Shell extension "Launch new instance". This is not installed by default, but is part of the "official" Gnome Shell extensions. You can install these with the command

```
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extensions
```

To enable or disable Gnome Shell extensions, you need either Gnome Tweaks (older versions) or Extensions (newer versions). Install these using Software or with the command.

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks gnome-shell-extension-prefs
```

After that, turn the extension on in, depending on your Ubuntu version, Extensions or Gnome Tweaks.